# user flag count in rules

Tags: 7, flags

Is it possible to add a condition - user flag count? Meaning to count every flag that user gave.
I could find only - user is flagged and user has flagging count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run the action "Fetch entity flag count" against the entity you're dealing with. In Rules you can have variables to store that and compare later.